# Multiple p-values calculator for Multiple Chi-Squared Values

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, p-value

This is not a theory question, just one of efficiency. Let's say I have a list (long list) of chi-squared random variables and I want to calculate a p-value for each. For ease let's say they all have the same degrees of freedom. Something like:

```
Chi Square [44,2.3, 33.4,........] -> p_value [.11,.95,.65,..........]
```

Is there a numpy function or online calculator that can do this? Losing my mind doing single entries atm.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`scipy.special.chdtrc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.chdtrc.html) (complement of the chi-square cumulative distribution function) or the `sf` (survival function) method of `scipy.stats.chi2` (which ultimately calls `scipy.special.chdtrc`).

For example,

```
In [63]: import numpy as np

In [64]: from scipy.special import chdtrc

In [65]: chi2vals = np.array([12, 5, 1.95, 4.2, 21.0])

In [66]: df = 9  # degrees of freedom

In [67]: chdtrc(df, chi2vals)  # p values
Out[67]: array([0.21330931, 0.83430826, 0.99223381, 0.8977626 , 0.01265042])

In [68]: from scipy.stats import chi2

In [69]: chi2.sf(chi2vals, df)  # p values
Out[69]: array([0.21330931, 0.83430826, 0.99223381, 0.8977626 , 0.01265042])
```

Comment: Bruh, thank you! Dope name btw. Cheers!